# Cross Platform Applications written in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

As I have seen there is a way through Xamarin and Visual Studio to develop cross platform applications in C#.

Is there a way to write cross platform applications with VB.net?
Is it possible Visual Studio 2017 to include this possibility?

Thank you!

Comment: No.  Xamarin only supports C# and F#.  There is no comparable platform that supports VB.NET.

Comment: If you want stick with a VB-like syntax but still want the ability to make cross-platform (and even iOS) apps, then check out Xojo: http://www.xojo.com

Comment: Thank you Paul. I will check Xojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VB.net in a xamarin forms project. You have to use a vb.net PCL for the project.   There is an article on the Xamarin site on how to do this.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/xamarin-forms/

Please note there are a lot of limitations on this.

Custom Renderers cannot be written in Visual Basic, they must be written in C# in the native platform projects.

Dependency Service implementations cannot be written in Visual Basic, they must be written in C# in the native platform projects.

XAML pages cannot be included in the Visual Basic project - the code-behind generator can only build C#. It is possible to include XAML in a separate, referenced, C# portable class library and use databinding to populate the XAML files via Visual Basic models (an example of this is included in the sample).

Xamarin does not support the Visual Basic.NET language.